Basement Hammock in 100+ Year Old House
I am looking to hang a hammock from the joists in my basement. The wood is over 100 years old, so I'm looking to do as little damage as possible to the material. I do not have appropriate angles to hang parallel to the joists, so I am looking for how to minimize any twist applied to the boards.
Details are as follows:

Joists are 2x6 lumber - species unknown at this time
Joists are supported with cross bridging.
Suspension points will be near foundation wall and center beam
Angle between suspension points is approximately 30 degrees
Hammock maximum weight is 400 lbs at a hang angle of 45 degrees
Maximum calculated static load on the suspension point assuming maximum load the hammock can support = 283 lbs
Maximum calculated shear load at suspension point = 200 lbs
Dynamic loads may be expected

Options I am currently considering:

A wrap around hanger on each joist:
Add blocking between two joists at each end. This would be the most difficult for me as I do not have access to a basic woodshop to get the correct measurements. This would allow better use of the hanger as listed in option 1.
Add strapping between two to three joists to distribute the load. I would be hanging from an appropriately rated eye bolt passed through the strapping. Also willing to run lag bolts at each connection point for added security.

Edit: Another hanger I found that I'm considering, since it seems to balance the mounted hanger above and the distributed load:
Are any of my options viable and which would be best given the constraints?

Use 2 hangers like you have pictured in option 1.  The joists are holding up 10s of thousands of pounds.  Your hammock should not be an issue and does not require rocket science.

@RMDman Thanks for the input. I figured I was over engineering the solution, but I wouldn't be here if I had the expertise to make the call on my own. Ironically, I do stage rigging. I'm just not a carpenter or structural engineer, lol.

@RMDman it may depend if the OP intends to swing on it (if it's parallel to the joist).

@Huesmann I'm not looking to do serious swinging like on a playground, but I would like the option for some dynamic loading. This is for a hammock, after all. I would like to be able to enjoy spending time with another person on it.
